# run a task using playbook on successful output of before task in windows

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm executing the below YAML(ansible) file using Jenkins. I want to execute task3 only after the successful execution/output of task2 and task2 only after task1 , My YAML file is as below. How do I add the dependency/condition for each of this task?

For example application.yml

```
-name: task1
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname"
 register: executeapp1

-name: task2
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp2

-name: task3
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp3
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior of Ansible to stop a playbook when a task failed:

> When Ansible receives a non-zero return code from a command or a failure from a module, by default it stops executing on that host and continues on other hosts.
> [Ansible playbooks error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

If that is not enough you can add a [condition based on registered variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#conditions-based-on-registered-variables) like so:

```
-name: task3
 win_command: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FRAMEWORK\V3.9.3013\MSBuild.exe" "E:\ApplicationFolder\App.xml" -target:Execute /p:ApplicationName="appname1"
 register: executeapp3
 when: executeapp2 is succeeded
```